# Radius of convergence of a Taylor-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I came across the following question.

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1+ c x^2}{1+ x^2}$$

Let $c \neq 1$. Determine for $a=0$ the convergence radius of the Taylor series of $f$ in the point $a$. What happens when $c=1$?

I tried to write down the Taylor series, the first derivative is easy but then it gets trickier.

$$ f'(x) = \frac{2x(c-1)}{1+ 2x^2 + x^4}$$

How can you determine the convergence radius of a Taylor series, especially if you cannot find a general formula for the series.

Comment: Use the binomial expansion (/geometric series formula).

Comment: Are you familiar with power series of holomorphic functions in the complex plane?

Comment: @Chappers I don't see how I could use this

Comment: @Martin R no I'm not, I don't know what holomorphic functions are but this question is part of a chapter about complex functions. So perhaps I should learn about this power series

Comment: $(1+x^2)^{-1} = 1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dotsb$. Multiply this by $(1+cx^2)$ (only two terms of the former series contribute to each term of the product, so this is doable).